# How will the call stack, event loop and microtask queue behave when executing this code?

Tags: javascript, promise, event-loop

I wanted to get some cached data in my API, and also make a DB update query. I've written the code and it works fine, but to my understanding it shouldn't. Can someone please explain how everything will be executed here?

```js
const slowDbUpdate = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            return res("DATA UPDATED");
        }, 10000);
    })
}

const fastCacheGet = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            return res({ cache: "fast", db: "slow" });
        }, 1000);
    })
}

const test = async () => {
    try {
        slowDbUpdate().then(res => console.log(res));
        const data = await fastCacheGet();

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error", error);
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
I am running this function, I just didn't bother writing it down.

```
test().then(res => console.log(res));
```

So this is what I understand should be happening:

1. The function `test` is pushed in the call stack and starts being executed.
2. JS calls the `slowDbUpdate` function, sees that it returns a promise, pushes the callback in the `.then` method into the microtask queue.
3. It then calls the `fastCacheGet` function, also pushes it into the queue.
4. (This is where I'm unsure) 1 second passes, the `fastCacheGet` promise resolves, but the event loop does not see the first promise to have resolved, and its callback is not called.
5. 10 seconds pass, the `slowDbUpdate` function resolves, the event loop pushes its callback onto the call stack, and then pushes the `fastCacheGet` callback onto the stack as well since it's already resolved.

But when I do run the code, it works like I want it to (i.e. returns the cached data (EDIT 2: logging `{ cache: "fast", db: "slow" }`) and logs "DATA UPDATED" 10 seconds later), not how I think it should. I've obviously misunderstood how JS works, any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT 1: I forgot to ask this as well, but I'm using a Node.js and express backend. Is what I'm trying to do even a good idea to begin with? This is the first time I'm trying to send the API response back without it having completed all it's work, so to speak. I don't think it should be an issue, but what will happen if I start doing this in a lot of APIs / this API is called very frequently. I know that I'll have to add a `.catch` to the end of such promises because it'll crash the app as an unhandled rejection in case it throws me an error, but what else can go wrong?

Comment: fastCacheGet resolves first, you are returning the data from the test function not logging it that's why maybe you are not able to see it. try this test().then(data => console.log(data))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me comment on the steps you have described:

> 1. The function test is pushed in the call stack and starts being executed.

Correct

> 2. JS calls the `slowDbUpdate` function, sees that it returns a promise, pushes the callback in the `.then` method into the microtask queue.

Nothing gets put in the microtask queue at this stage. The `then` callback is "only" registered by the promise API (as private info of the promise instance).

> 3. It then calls the `fastCacheGet` function, also pushes it into the queue.

`fastCachet` returns a promise instance that has a pending state, but nothing is put in a queue here. The `await` operator has the following effect:

1. the promise (returned by `fastCacheGet`) gets the task (as private info) that would resume the `test` function at the point below the `await` operator.
2. the function `test` returns(!), and it returns a pending promise to the main program.

> 4. (This is where I'm unsure) 1 second passes, the `fastCacheGet` promise resolves, but the event loop does not see the first promise to have resolved, and its callback is not called.

I think the source of the confusion might be that you think `await` blocks any further execution. But this is not true. `test()` returns when it executes the `await` operator, and then the main program also finishes (after calling `.then` to register a callback), so that the event loop can happily do its work while all created promises are still pending.

When about one second has passed, the `setTimeout` callback is placed on a job queue (by the host implementation of the `setTimeout` API), and the event loop detects and executes it. The call to `resolve` resolves the fast promise, which has a registered `then` callback, and places that callback in the microtask queue. The event loop detects that callback and executes it, so that after approximately one second you get the expected output.

> 10 seconds pass, the `slowDbUpdate` function resolves, the event loop pushes its callback onto the call stack, and then pushes the `fastCacheGet` callback onto the stack as well since it's already resolved.

As explained above, the `fastCacheGet` callback has already executed at a time the `test` function execution was suspended. When about 10 seconds have passed and the `setTimeout` callback executes, the "slow" promise resolves. It has a suspended function context (of `test`), and so it places its restoration on the microtask queue. The event loop detects and executes this, i.e. the `test` execution context is revived, and its execution resumes until its end. When its `return` statement is executed, the main promise (that was returned 10 seconds earlier) is now also fulfilled.